# Can't get knockout running

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm a complete noob in knockoutjs and I'm facing a problem just from the beginning. I have done everything described in the installation guide, but I can't get it working.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout-3.0.0.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/myTasks.js'></script>
      <TITLE>Your Tasks</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
     <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
     <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

My viewmodel - contained in the `myTasks.js` file:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

What I'm getting is:

```
First name:

Last name:
```

The above code is the code used in the first knockoutjs tutorial.

Why I can't run it? I know that I'm missin something really small, but I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: `$( document ).ready( function() {} );`? And developer's console

Comment: @u_mulder Btw the console says: `TypeError: c is null`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Wrap you knockout code in `$( document ).ready( function() {} );`

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    function AppViewModel() {
        this.firstName = "Bert";
        this.lastName = "Bertington";
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
} );
```

And don't forget to include jquery itself.

Comment: Only the last KO line must be inside `document.ready()`. The function(s) like `AppViewModel()` may be outside of that.

Answer (score 17):

I know this question was answered a long time ago, but it is one of the top searches on Google when searching for solutions on this issue.  You should *not* have to use JQuery with knockout.js as is implied by the accepted answer. A better solution would be to just move your script tag referencing myTask.js to the bottom of your body:

```
<BODY>
 <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
 <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/myTasks.js'></script>
</BODY>
```

This should allow your viewmodel code to work without having to include jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. This was a much better solution because it eliminates the need for an outside dependency.